# Is mapping $f$, where $f(x) = x^2$, of an open set $(1, 5)$ (say) $\subset$ $R$ into $R$ a continuously differentiable mapping (a $C'$ mapping)?

Tags: analysis, linear-transformations

In *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin, we have the following definition:

> A differentiable mapping $\mathbf f$ of an open set $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R^m$ is said to be *continuously differentiable* if $E$ if $\mathbf f'$ is a continuous mapping of $E$ into $L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$.
>
> More explicitly, it is required that to every $\mathbf x \in E$ and to every $\epsilon > 0$ corresponds a $\delta > 0$ such that $$ \left\| \mathbf f'(\mathbf y) - \mathbf f'(\mathbf x) \right\| < \epsilon$$ if $\mathbf y \in E$ and $\|\mathbf x - \mathbf y \| < \delta$.
>
> If this is so, we also say that $\mathbf f$ is a $C'$-mapping, or that $\mathbf f \in C'(E)$.

So is the function $f : (1, 5) \to \mathbb R$, with $f(x) = x^2$, a continuously differentiable mapping (a $C'$ mapping)?

$f'(x)=2x$ is continuous on $(1,5)$. But is $f$ a continuously differentiable mapping? For it to be continuously differentiable, the definition seems to need $f'$ to be a mapping from $(1,5)$ into $L(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$.

Here I am not understanding the elements of $L(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$. Are the elements of $L(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ the subsets of $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, such that it is a linear transformation?

Then, I am not understanding how range of $f'$ can be of the form of subset of $L(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$.

$f'$ here seems to have a range that is a subset of $\mathbb R$, and not a subset of $L(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$. So perhaps $f$ is not a continuously differentiable mapping or a $C'$ mapping?

---

**Note:** My definition of functions/mappings comes from *Mathematical Analysis* by Apostol:

> A function $F$ is a set of ordered pairs $(x, y)$, no two of which have the same first member. That is, if $(x, y) \in  F$ and $(x, z) \in F$, then $y = z$.

My definition of $L(X, Y)$ comes from *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin:

> Let $L(X, Y)$ be the set of all linear transformations of the vector space $X$ into the vector space $Y$.

> A mapping $A$ of a vector space $X$ to a vector space $Y$ is said to be a linear transformation if $$A(\mathbf x_1 + \mathbf x_2) = A(\mathbf x_1) + A(\mathbf x_2), \qquad A(c\mathbf x) = cA(\mathbf x)$$
> for all $\mathbf x, \mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2 \in X$ and $c \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Rudin's textbook seems to have different meanings for f' and **f'**.

Answer (score 3):

Given $a \in \mathbb{R}$, it determines an element of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, precisely the linear map, $x \mapsto ax$. In your case, $f' : (1,5) \to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, which you need to show is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an unfortunate notation decision: here the $f'$ from Rudin refers to what you can also see be named $df$ or $Df$, the differential of $f$, which maps $x$ to a linear map $df_x(\cdot)$ or $Df(x)(\cdot)$.
The $f'$ you're used to is the notation for the function which maps $x$ to the real $f'(x)$ specifically for a function $f : I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $Df(x)(h) = f'(x) h$, as linear maps are all of this form for $L(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer allowed me see Rudin having different meaning for f' and **f'**.

Comment: You're welcome.